# List comprehensions without filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, list-comprehension

Recently came across this piece of code online:

```
nonprime = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
```

The above code seems to be calculating all the non primes below 50,but I am not getting the logic. 
I studied list comprehensions in python and observed it uses filter to filter based on conditions, 
but all I cannot understand how two for loops are calculating these non primes.

Comment: This is just two nested loops. No filtering. That it works has probably nothing to do with python, but is some clever numerical thing - I’m white positive it stops working for bigger numbers.

Comment: @deets, You're right that's it's a "clever numerical thing" (see [the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431930/prove-that-if-a-number-n-1-is-not-prime-then-it-has-a-prime-factor-le-sq)). But since it has been proved Mathematically, it does work, albeit inefficiently, for bigger numbers.

Comment: yes indeed.. many solutions were helpful and it was hard to tick one.
Thanks a lot to all for elaborated explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this answer lies in Mathematics:

[If a number n>1 is not prime, then it has a prime factor <= sqr(n)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431930/prove-that-if-a-number-n-1-is-not-prime-then-it-has-a-prime-factor-le-sq)

Now we are left to explain the logic. Note that `sqrt(50) < 8`, which is the limit of the first `range`.

We may rewrite the nested list comprehension as a regular loop. We can use `set` instead of a list, which will have unnecessary repeated elements:

```
res = set()

for i in range(2, 8):
    for j in range(i*2, 50, i):
        res.add(j)
```

The outer loop iterates all `i < sqrt(50)`.

The inner loop iterates, for each `i`, all multiples of `i` less than 50.

By the aforementioned Mathematical statement, we have all non-primes under 50. This is true because we are exhausting *all* prime factors <= sqrt(50).

Answer (score 3):

This list comprehension does the same as these two nested for loops:

```
nonprime=[]
for i in range(2,8):
    for j in range(i*2, 50,i):
        nonprime.append(j)
```

So in the outer loop, `i` is just increased by one in every iteration, and takes on the values i=2,3,4,5,6,7.
The inner for loop over `j` depends on the outer loop. It starts at `2*i` and `j` is increased by `i` in each iteration.

So for `ì=2`, the inner loop starts at `j=4` and `j` takes on the values  `j=4,6,8,...,48`.
Then `ì` is increased to 3 in the outer loop and `j` takes on the values `6,9,12,...48`

Notice that the `nonprime` list does not create unique elements, since for example the 6 appears more than once.

As Bakuriu rightfully points out, this method makes use of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 2):

The loops are basically the [Sieve of Erathostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), but instead of removing numbers they keep them.

In the Sieve of Erathostenes you *remove* multiples of "known primes". The most efficient way to do this is, given a prime `p`, to remove the number `p*p` then `p*(p+1)` etc until you reach the limit and continue with the next prime `q`, and start a `q*q`.

The list comprehension is a minor variation of this. You can replace `i*2` with `i*i` and still obtain the same numbers (although with less repetitions).

In the Sieve of Erathostenes you usually remove all even numbers except for `2` and then use `2*i` as the step of the range, since you only have to consider odd numbers for primeness. Obviously this is not true if you want to obtain all non-primes so that "optimization" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the non list comprehension version of that code:

```
nonprime = []
for i in range(2, 8):
    for j in range(i*2, 50, i):
        nonprime.append(j)
```

Step by step:

```
for i in range(2, 8):
```

So far, pretty simple. This will return the numbers 2 through 7, stopping when it gets to 8. In the first iteration of this loop, `i = 2`.

```
    for j in range(i*2, 50, i):
```

Now we're creating an inner loop. Let's replace `i` with 2, so we can see what it's doing on the first iteration of the *outer* loop.

```
    for j in range(2*2, 50, 2):
```

or

```
    for j in range(4, 50, 2)
```

This returns a list of numbers starting with 4, and stepping up 2 each time (6, 8, 10) and stops when it gets to 50. If you look at the results in `nonprime` you'll see these numbers.

The next iteration of the outer loop, `i = 3`. So:

```
    for j in range(i*2, 50, i):
```

Becomes:

```
    for j in range(3*2, 50, 3):
```

Or:

```
    for j in range(6, 50, 3):
```

Starting with 6, we keep adding 3 and stop when we get to 50. You'll see this sequence appear next in the list of values present in `nonprime`

That's it, that's all this code is doing. As @Bakuriu pointed out this is basically a [Sieve of Erathostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in reverse, but that's another subject.

Answer (score 0):

It basically calculates all multiples of values from range(2, 8) lower than 50. It will contain **duplicated** values.

```
# iterates over values in this range [2, 7]
for i in range(2, 8)

# iterates over multiples of i lower than 50
for j in range(i*2, 50, i)
```

The result will look like this:

```
[ 4, 6, 8, ... # multiples of 2 lower than 50
 6, 9, 12, ... # multiples of 3 lower than 50
(...)
14, 21, 28, ... # multiples of 7 lower than 50
]
```